# Is there a browser/management view in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, data-management

Is there a browser/management view in QGIS 1.8 so that I can manipulate shapefiles and others (such as geo tiffs, etc.) like in ArcCatalog? Maybe a plugin? Right now I have to use my system's file manager to manage them, but is error prone because I have to select five files for a shapefile, instead of just on in ArcCatalog.

BTW, I found the builtin browser dock, but can't get it to do any manipulation other than drag it into the TOC.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/are-there-open-source-alternatives-to-arccatalog

Comment: Not exactly, because I am hoping for something that runs within QGIS.

Comment: the browser is just that - a browser to select files/layers

Comment: yes, I have the same question. In the qgis browser i can´t copy shp files and paste or move to another folder. because I have to select 5 files for each shp file (.shp, .dbf, .shx, etc.)

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. It should be added below the question as a comment.

Answer (score 6):

There's a plugin called ["QGIS File Browser"](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/file-browser/wiki), but it does not let you manipulate files in the system file hierarchy, only filter them by type (raster, vector, SHP, etc) and add them to the layers in the project.

[wxGIS](http://code.google.com/p/wxgis/) is a project following the ArcGIS model with a browser and toolbox which aim to replicate ArcCatalog and ArcToolbox functionality; there is an installer for Windows and an Ubuntu package available.

Comment: If you are going to be running QGIS 1.8 the file browser plugin is deprecated in favour of the built in QGIS Browser dock.

Comment: @Nathan W Yes I tried the QGIS 1.8 browser dock, but it doesn't seem to let me do any manipulations?

Answer (score 3):

You can use QGIS Browser or wxGIS for that.

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something, but I can see files via the QGIS 1.8 browser, but can't do any manipulations?